# mysql 5.3 - some error, but query seems ok

Tags: mysql

> mysql query - error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a', '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1' at line 1

The query that fails:

```
INSERT INTO tags (ip, tag, count) 
  VALUES ('xx.xx.xxx.xxx', 'krwiopijcy', '1') 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1;
```

Is there anything wrong in my query?

Comment: The query you have pasted and the error message do not match.  There is no `'a', '1')` in your query.  Please post the *exact* query that failed to execute.

Comment: Error statement does not match with the insert statement. Can you post the query that had `... 'a', '1') ...` in it?

Comment: it's weird coz this is the query of error. wait a sec

Comment: here is another example: [Wednesday, July 18, 2012 05:35:32 pm] mysql query - error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'po', '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1' at line 1
[Wednesday, July 18, 2012 05:35:32 pm] query: INSERT INTO tags (ip, tag, count) VALUES ('xx.xx.xxx.xxx', 'umacku'', '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1;

Comment: and you say it isnt match, but it should, "po" "umacku" was a one record

Comment: @KamilKrzyszczuk That error message still does not match the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` is a built in function and as such, [may require care to be used as such](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). However, as the docs say, it is perfectly fine as column name. You might want to escape it using

```
`count`
```

That being said, I had no problem with your exact query (no escaping) using this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `ip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `count` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Your example from the comments has one apostrophe too much (behind 'umacku'), which doesn't seem to be the problem (as it is not given in the error message), but you should paste the exact queries:

```
INSERT INTO tags (ip, tag, count)
    VALUES ('xx.xx.xxx.xxx', 'umacku'', '1')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1;
```

Comment: Yes, big thanks! hmm i use node.js and extension for mysql, and there is escape function but what i see it doesn't work well because of this apostrophe

Comment: @Kamil Not my business but... Worlfram provides a quality answer, you thank him but you don't increase the answer rate, and don't accept his answer. Any reason to that?